# Convergence/divergence of sum of finite products of functions of reciprocals of natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, pigeonhole-principle, infinite-product, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

Convergence/divergence of sum of finite products of functions of reciprocals of natural numbers where the product of the functions equals the identity function.

Yes that was quite the mouthful.

Proposition:

If $$\ \prod\limits_{i = 1}^n  {f_i(x)} = x \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+,\ $$ then

$$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty \left( {\prod\limits_{i = 1}^n  {\frac{1}{f_i(a_{ki})}} } \right) $$

converges for some rearrangement $\ (a_{ki})_{i \in {1,...,n }\ and \ k \in \mathbb{N}} \ $ of $\mathbb{N}$, and diverges for some other rearrangement $\ (a_{ki})_{i \in {1,...,n }\ and \ k \in \mathbb{N}} \ $ of $\mathbb{N}$.

Note that I require $a_{ki} \neq a_{k'i'}$ if $k \neq k'$ or $i \neq i'$, i.e. $(a_{ki})$ is a sequence of natural numbers **bijective** to $\mathbb{N}$.

Is this true?

An example of it working is:

$f_1(x) = f_2(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$.

An example of divergence: $\frac{1}{\sqrt 1} . \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} . \frac{1}{\sqrt 4} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 5} . \frac{1}{\sqrt 6} + ... > \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} + ... = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... \right)$, which diverges.

An example of convergence: $\frac{1}{\sqrt 1} . \frac{1}{\sqrt 5000} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} . \frac{1}{\sqrt 8} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} . \frac{1}{\sqrt 27} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 4} . \frac{1}{\sqrt 64} + ... = \frac{1}{\sqrt 5000} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{16} + ...,\ $ which converges. I have ignored the repetitions here (for example $\frac{1}{\sqrt 8} . \frac{1}{\sqrt 512}$ isn't a term because that would be a repeat of $\frac{1}{\sqrt 8}$), but I think it's not difficult to modify this "fake sequence" and make it into one that works.

I'm quite sure it works for $n$th roots using AM-GM to show divergence and using similar methods for rearrangements for the square root example I showed above.